# int Array with empty value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, chart.js

I have have this string `"[,,3,,]"` now i have set with this string the data attribute of chartjs.

```
chart.data.datasets.push({
  label: label,
  data: DataArray,
  lineTension: 0.3,
  pointBorderColor: 'blue',
  pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,150,0,0.5)',
  pointRadius: 5,
  pointHoverRadius: 10,
  pointHitRadius: 30,
  pointBorderWidth: 2,
  pointStyle: 'rectRounded'
});
```

but it can't be a string. how i can do it?

Comment: How are you generating that string? It would be better to fix the code which generates that flawed content instead of hacking a solution to work with it

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this string to Array, create a new function to parse the string and return it using [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!), but this will create an Array with undefined Objects:

```js
function looseJsonParse(obj){
    return Function('"use strict";return (' + obj + ')')();
}
const str = "[,,3,,]";
const DataArray = looseJsonParse(str);

console.log(DataArray);
```

you can simply [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the elements if you want just only valid values in your data array:

```js
function looseJsonParse(obj){
    return Function('"use strict";return (' + obj + ')')();
}
const str = "[,,3,,]";
const DataArray = looseJsonParse(str).filter(el => el);

console.log(DataArray);
```

Comment: Isn't your `looseJsonParse()` function essentially the same as `eval()`?

Comment: @Barmar, this from MDN, linked above, its safer than `eval()` as they claim.